# java.lang.IllegalStateException: sequencer not open

Tags: java

Всем привет!

Есть такой код:

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class MiniMiniMusicApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MiniMiniMusicApp mini = new MiniMiniMusicApp();
    mini.play();
  }

  public void play(){
    try {
        Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer(true);
        Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
        Track track = seq.createTrack();

        ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
        a.setMessage(144, 1, 44, 100);
        MidiEvent noteOn = new MidiEvent(a, 1);
        track.add(noteOn);

        ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
        b.setMessage(128, 1, 44, 100);
        MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(b, 16);
        track.add(noteOff);

        player.setSequence(seq);

        player.start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Пишет ошибку

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: sequencer not open at
>   com.sun.media.sound.RealTimeSequencer.start(RealTimeSequencer.java:243)
>   at MiniMiniMusicApp.play(MiniMiniMusicApp.java:28) at
>   MiniMiniMusicApp.main(MiniMiniMusicApp.java:7)

Вроде все же правильно в коде написано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо открыть Sequencer

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class MiniMiniMusicApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MiniMiniMusicApp mini = new MiniMiniMusicApp();
        mini.play();
    }

    public void play(){
        try {
            Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer(true);
            player.open();
            Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
            Track track = seq.createTrack();

            ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
            a.setMessage(144, 1, 44, 100);
            MidiEvent noteOn = new MidiEvent(a, 1);
            track.add(noteOn);

            ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
            b.setMessage(128, 1, 44, 100);
            MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(b, 16);
            track.add(noteOff);

            player.setSequence(seq);

            player.start();
            player.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло